# How to query to get the current custom post’s value in a single post page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I put the code below in a single post page. 
The problem is it displays correct title of the current post but incorrent count number.
It shows count 0, when the actual count is 1. 
Current post has purchased=yes and firstsubmission=yest, so it should display 1.
I trid 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), instead of 'title' => get_the_title(), and 'posts_per_page'   => 1, but still shows count 0. 
Would you please help me correct the code?

```
$info_args = [
    'author'          => get_current_user_id(),
    'title'           => get_the_title(),
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, 
    'post_type'       => 'infosubmission',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_query'      => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'purchased',
               'value' => 'yes',
               'compare' => '=',
               'key' => 'firstsubmission',
               'value' => 'yes',
               'compare' => '=',           
           )
       )
];

$info_info_posts = get_posts($info_args);
$info_info_count = count($info_info_posts);

echo 'Title: ' . get_the_title() .'<br>';
echo 'Count:' .$info_info_count ;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simple trying to get a count of all the posts belonging to a certain custom post type, just use this instead, as it's much faster:

```
$info_info_count = wp_count_posts( 'infosubmission' )->publish;
```

Unfortunately this function won't let you filter by anything except post status, so if that's required, then you'll need to create a secondary query.

Firstly, you can't query this way by title, so leave that out (it would have restricted your query to only the current post/page anyway). Second, your `meta_query` argument isn't formatted correctly for multiple fields. Try this instead:

```
$info_args = [
    'author'          => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, 
    'post_type'       => 'infosubmission',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'meta_query'      => array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
           array(
               'key' => 'purchased',
               'value' => 'yes',
               // 'compare' is '=' by default, so not needed here.
           ),
           array(
               'key' => 'firstsubmission',
               'value' => 'yes',          
           ),
       ),
];

$info_info_posts = get_posts( $info_args );
$info_info_count = count( $info_info_posts );

echo 'Title: ' . get_the_title() . '<br>';
echo 'Count: ' . $info_info_count;
```

Additionally, functions like `get_the_title()` use the global `$post` object by default, so unless you provide an argument or call `the_post()` again, it will only get the title of the current page. So I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but if you wanted to, for example, print the title of *each* post returned by your new query, you would need to start another loop to iterate through the results. In that case I would recommend creating a new `WP_Query` independent of the main one:

```
$info_posts = new WP_Query( $info_args );
$count_info_posts = $info_posts_query->found_posts;

echo 'Count: ' . $count_info_posts . '<br>';

//Start The Loop
while ( $info_posts->have_posts() ) : $info_posts->the_post();
    echo 'Title: ' . get_the_title() .'<br>';
    // Do anything else you'd like with each post's data here.
endwhile;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note on multiple queries [from the WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/):

> Note: If you use `the_post()` with your query, you need to run `wp_reset_postdata()` afterwards to have template tags use the main query’s current post again.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you a lot for your detailed explanation. It was a big hlep. : )

Answer (score 0):

Your meta query wrong you have to make a separate array for each meta key compare. check the below code.

```
$info_args = [
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'title'          => get_the_title(),
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type'      => 'infosubmission',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'purchased',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(       
            'key'     => 'firstsubmission',
            'value'   => 'yes',
            'compare' => '=',           
        )
    )
];

$info_info_posts = get_posts($info_args);
$info_info_count = count($info_info_posts);

echo 'Title: ' . get_the_title() .'<br>';
echo 'Count:' .$info_info_count ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Bhautik : )

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Actually it didn't work but still thank you for your comments : )